# admin url redirects to customer view page in magento2.3

Tags: admin, redirect, magento2.3

I am a beginner to magento. I am currently using magento version 2.3 and
http://localhost/myproject/admin url redirects to customer view page instead of appearance of admin login form. Thank you in advance.